# OwnerDrawLabelProvider makes column text selections blue even after calling erase method

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I am using jface Tableviewer which uses OwnerDrawLabelProvider. I was getting blue background for row selection as shown below

[image]

Then i called erase method to remove background color. After using erase method its removed only row background color. For text selection its still showing blue background (as shown below)

[image]

Here is my code

```
@Override
protected void measure(Event event, Object element) {

}

@Override
protected void paint(Event event, Object element) {
    LogTestData logtest = null;
    Rectangle bounds = event.getBounds();
    event.gc.drawText(" ", bounds.x, bounds.y);
    // Point point = event.gc.stringExtent(" ");
    if (element instanceof LogTestData) {
        logtest = (LogTestData) element;
    }
    int index = event.index;
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        if (logtest.getIconInfo().equals(ActivityLog.INFO_LOG)) {
            event.gc.drawImage(infoImage, bounds.x, bounds.y);
        } 
       ................
       ................
    default:
        break;
    }

}

@Override
protected void erase(Event event, Object element) {

}
```

How can I remove backgroungd color for text selection. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `erase` method turn off the event selected flag:

```
event.detail &= ~SWT.SELECTED;
```

Comment: This will remove the control over the table.  After disabling the event  need to explicitly set background as white. thank you!